# QT выдает ошибку при запуске

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator

выдает ошибку при запуске проекта. Путь к файлу C:\Sourse\qt, пробелов не содержит, путь на английском, не содержит русских символом (знаю, что ругается на них). Не могу понять в чем дело
[image]

Comment: lnk1181 - это "не может найти файл". но судя по картинке - там действительно идет попытка найти файл, у которого есть только расширение. Странно:) Показывайте свой pro (или там уже cmake файл) и удалите российскую локализацию. Она будет в будущем только вредить.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чем ошибка была:
SOURCES += \ нужна всего одна , до этого менял, что странно, видимо не сохранилось просто